# what is the best approach to create docker containers that are able to communicate with each other?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a pipeline script that I have a server container, and a client container that runs certain chaos testing on the server, when using Kuubernetes, I noticed that all containers are on localhost, which will fail my tests, so what is the right approach to have 2 containers that can communicate on different IPs/hostnames?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about jenkins, but in Kubernetes all containers that are inside a pod will communicate using localhost. It's behaving like a sidecar application, rather than client-server application.

If you want to simulate client and server application, I would suggest to use 2 Kubernetes pods (1 pod for server and 1 pod for client).

Comment: someone told me I can use docker-compose rather than using kubernetes, do you think that'd work in my case?

Comment: yes, if you use docker you can do it.

Comment: You might read [Networking in (Docker) Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and [DNS for (Kubernetes) Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) as starting points.  To reemphasize @Raymond's answer, you normally want only one container in a Kubernetes Pod, and you'd have separate Deployments for the client and the server.

Comment: using docker-compose (or docker swarm) you can use service name as targert FQDN. Not sure if it works in K8S same way